# How to setup virtual users for sftp (sshd) with access to a specific sub directory?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, sftp, pam, sshd

I try to setup virtual users for sftp with sshd and/or pam.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/
|-- var
|   +-- www
|       +-- site1
|           +-- folder_1
|           +-- folder_2
|       +-- site2
|           +-- folder_1
|           +-- folder_2
```

Each site dose have a Linux user (e.g. site1, site2) with the same group (site1, site2) where the home directory is e.g. `/var/www/site1`. The umask is 0022 and all files and (sub)folders for e.g. `site1` have `UID=site1` anf `GID=site1` and this should not be changed.

I was able to setup sshd so that each Linux user gets his home directory as sftp root folder is e.g. `/var/www/site1` for user `site1`. The config in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks something like this
(only last few lines, the rest is default configuration):

```
UsePAM yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User *,!root
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0022
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Now I want to add a Virtual User (no new Linux user or group if not needed) where the sftp root folder is e.g. `/var/www/site1/folder1` for a sftp user e.g. `site1_folder1`. This user should be a child of the user `site1` and use the same UID and GID but only have access to his subdirectory.

How do I have to change my configuration, and where can I add Virtual User?

*I need this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, LAMP Server*

Comment: OpenSSH uses PAM (sshd_config file directive UsePAM) PAM.
You just need to learn how to setup pam-libpsql with it - which should be an hour or so. So yes, you can have virtual users, but you will probably need to add UID/GUID field in your DB to every user. If what HellionWisp said was true, you could never setup LDAP or any external form of Authentication/Authorization. Take a look at /etc/pam.d/sshd - but I would not recommend messing up with it on a remote host, test it in local VM first! You can actually look for SSH ldap auth for hints!

Answer (score 3):

ProFTPd allows you to create virtual FTP/SFTP users and map them to a real user's uid and gid.

Comment: SFTP ≠ FTPS !!!
ProFTPd is an FTP server, that also supports FTPS, which is FTP over TLS. SFTP on the other hand is a method of transfering files over an SSH connection, that has nothing in common with traditional FTP.

Comment: ProFTPd  is an FTP server, but it also supports SFTP connections http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that feature of ProFTPd, so I thought you just mixed this up. However, I will leave my comment anyway, so that other's might get the hint.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as a virtual user, anyone connecting will need a user account, and you can chroot jail them in their respective home directory.

Comment: But I neet the same UID and GUI ... I know this is posible some how... one Webprovider do it but I don't know how...